# Looping through an associative array with the same key

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, associative-array

I am currently trying to loop through an associative array. This array contains values with the same key. However, when I tried to loop through it, I only get one set of results. How can I loop through all the values containing the same key?

```
#!/bin/bash/
declare -A details=( [dog]="golden retriver" [cat]="bengal" [bird]="eagle" [dog]="bulldog" [cat]="sphynx" [bird]="parakeet" )

for k in "${!details[@]}"
do
  echo $k --- ${details[$k]}
done
```

Result:

```
cat --- sphynx
dog --- bulldog
bird --- parakeet
```

Comment: To see complete associative array: `declare -p details`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as having several values associated with the same key of an associative array in bash. The last one simply overrides the previous one. That's why you cannot retrieve it. To prove this, you could print the size of the array, and see that it's 3 and not 6:

```
mureinik@computer ~ $ declare -A details=( [dog]="golden retriver" [cat]="bengal" [bird]="eagle" [dog]="bulldog" [cat]="sphynx" [bird]="parakeet" )
mureinik@computer ~ $ echo ${#details[@]} 
3
```

Comment: Use distinct keys. If you really need multiple values associated with each key, `bash` is the wrong language for the job.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student, you could accomplish that if instead of having the values as strings, make them an array - to which you'd append any new value that comes for the same key.